# Swift Take A Dictionary from plist

Tags: swift, ios8

I Save my Button in one file plist

```
<dict>
<key>NameButton</key>
<array>
    <string>Button 1</string>
    <string>Button 2</string>
    <string>Button 3</string>
    <string>Button 4</string>
    <string>Button 5</string>
</array>
<key>NumberButton</key>
<string>5</string>
<key>button</key>
<dict>
    <key>Button 1</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Button 2</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Button 4</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Button 5</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Button 6</key>
    <string>0</string>
</dict>
```

i can get a NameButton from plist in this mode

```
 var Name:[String] = data!.valueForKey("NameButton") as [String]
```

and if i want to get the Dictionary Button from plist ?
and for example if i want to change a value of Button 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    if var d = data {
        //get 'button' dictionary
        var button = d["button"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        if var b = button {
            //get 'Button 4' value
            var button4 = b["Button 4"] as? String
            println(button4)
            if let b4 = button4 {
                //change 'Button 4' value
                b["Button 4"] = "5"
                println(b["Button 4"])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for i see if i get the dictionary button i have tried with only var button = data["button"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> println(button) i have this Optional([:])

Comment: i get this
    `Optional(["Button 6": 0, "Button 1": 0, "Button 2": 0, "Button 5": 0, "Button 4": 0])`
   are you sure you are doing the same?

Comment: yes in the same place if i insert var Name:[String] = data!.valueForKey("NameButton") as [String]  println(Name)

Comment: i have [Button 1, Button 2, Button 3]

Comment: if i insert var Name2 = data!["button"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  println(Name2) i don't get a value from plist

Comment: how do you initialise your data variable?